# disable parent window when child window is open extjs 4

Tags: extjs, parent-child

In my app I have a main window with a button that opens another window. How can I disable the parent window until the child one is open?

Code in click listener:

```
var editWindow = new Ext.Window({
                            id: 'editWindow',
                            width: 400,
                            layout: {
                                type: 'vbox',
                                align: 'stretch'
                            },
                            items: [ editPanel ],
                        });
                        editWindow.show();
```

Comment: Can you post your code on how you open the child window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `modal: true` config on your `Ext.Window` object.

If you're trying to complete disable the parent's window, you can use `disable()` method on your parent view.